# How to Pass URL param in form on submit?

Tags: php, forms

I have

`<form name="feedback" method="post" onsubmit="return checkform()" action="engine.php?ad=">`

and I need to append a variable to

`engine.php?ad=`, which is

`<?=$_GET['page'];?>` in php (pass a URL param to the next page using this.)

How would I go about adding that?

I also have it in javascript if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<form name="feedback" 
      method="post" 
      onsubmit="return checkform()" 
      action="engine.php?ad=<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['page']); ?>">
```